# Use of Persistent Store Co-ordinators?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, core-data, nspersistentstore

I have made an iPad app that is based primarily on table view controllers/table views. I am getting the content for it from .csv files on an external server. I need to save the content on the device. So I am using core data to achieve this. I have managed to successfully use Managed Objects and Managed Object Contexts to do this. If the user provides input, for a new cell, I store it in a managed object.

However, after doing all this, I never needed to use Persistent Store Co-ordinators. Well maybe I should have, but I don't know how or why to use them.

A bit of enlightenment on this would be great!

EDIT: So my question is, are persistent store co-ordinators needed for core data? What are they used for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A persistent store coordinator is the link between the physical data base (store file) and the managed object context. You can't work with core data without a persistent store coordinator. The context tracks changes to your managed objects. The managed object model describes all the entities (relationship, properties etc.).

Comment: So do I need to make an NSPersistentStore or is it done automatically in the background?

Comment: The NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is instantiated during core data initialization. In Xcode create a new project from the Master-Detail Application and have a look into it.